# magento2 custom category controller err

Tags: magento2, category

**UPDATED**etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Tagalys\Tglssearch\Block\Catalog\Product\ListProduct" />
```

Should i override the \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct.php listproduct in **etc.di or etc/frontend/di.xml**

I get the core method executed

Comment: For _getProductCollection()

Answer (score 1):

Check following change

```
use Tagalys\Tglssearch\Controller\Catalog\CategoryController;
use Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Design;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class CategoryController extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View
{
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;
    protected $_catalogSession;
    protected $_catalogDesign;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $categoryUrlPathGenerator;
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $resultForwardFactory;
    private $layerResolver;
    protected $categoryRepository;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View $viewHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        .....
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $viewHelper, $resultForwardFactory, $resultPageFactory);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_catalogDesign = $catalogDesign;
        ....
    }
}
```

Don't forget to delete **var/generation/Tagalys**